# How can I improve the vocabulary I use?

Tags: vocabulary

I've realized that when I write or speak English, the vocabulary that I use is a lot more limited than the vocabulary that I know. For example, when writing, some words which I know the meaning to and *are* in my vocabulary don't occur to me and I'm limited to a smaller range of vocabulary and since I'm writing more these days, I'd like to improve this... any ideas?

Comment: (I've migrated this question since it doesn't just apply to English, I guess.)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. I think you'll find helpful tips in the answers to the question [How can I expand my active vocabulary in a foreign language?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/744/800)